# Override jade parent template loading mechanism

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I would like to know if it is possible to override the mechanism jade loads templates to inherit from. Think of the following snippet:

```
extends layout
block stuff
  h1 My stuff
```

If this is saved as `/dir/template.jade` jade will look for `/dir/layout.jade` what I want is to load `layout.jade` from a database during rendering. So I'm looking for something like:

```
jade.render( "...", {
    loadParent: function( path ) {
        return db.get({ id: path });
    }
});
```

I couldn't find any hint in the documentation. Have you ever heard of something like this?

Looking forward to hear from you,
Dominik

Comment: This won't be dynamic rendering, but dynamic compiling. If possible better use templates. The maitainers have accepted the way to work as static compile-then-dynamic render to optimize performance. See this post on details of dynamic request : https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1312